# Getting a DB Error: unknown error when entering and saving phone number

Tags: wordpress, database, error

I see that there's a few threads out there around this topic. I've just installed a brand new instance of WordPress 4.4 with CiviCRM 4.6.10. I've got three other installs of CiviCRM with Drupal on this same host, so, I can't imagine that it's a problem with the host.

Here's a portion of the log:

Dec 14 21:53:32  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -1
[message] => DB Error: unknown error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_numeric' [nativecode=1548 ** Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_numeric' [nativecode=1548 ** Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_numeric' [nativecode=1548 ** Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted]"]
```

)

Database is 5.5.47-MariaDB. The user account has "ALL PRIVILEGES".

Any thoughts? Any help is *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Totally weird. I just started googling on the error and actually found a post (from myself!) from a year and a half ago: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32308.0. Same error, same host. I'll contact them to see if they can fix.

Comment: seems like a sql upgrade is needed. Can you try with `mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mysql function that is called to save a normalized phone number (stripping spaces and so on). You seem to have a problem as mysql can't load this function

Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted

This might be several issues and potentially indicating bigger issues, database corruption should be handled seriously.

The indicated fix might work:

```
mysql_upgrade
```

Backup the database first. if it doesn't solve the problem, restore it on a different server (or on your laptop) and check if you can get a working civicrm there.

Comment: They ran the following: mysql_upgrade -uroot -p. This fixed the issue. Thanks!